# How to create a topic using old registration tokens

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Our service collected GCM tokens using [deprecated `gcm.register()` method](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid#registration-state-sync-handling).
We are planning to use topics, but the tokens cannot be used in [Create relationship maps for app instances](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance) API because that API is for Instance ID.

Is there any way to get the new IID tokens from the old tokens, or to create a mapping using the old tokens WITHOUT updating client app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accepted noogui's answer, but I found a way.

[GCM Send API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) accepts `registration_ids` parameter. If an old token is included in this list, the API responds new registration_id.
For example

```
$ curl -v https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: key=GCM_API_KEY' --data '
{
  "registration_ids" : ["(old registration id)"],
  "data" : {"message": "hello"}
}
'
>> {"multicast_id":123456,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,
    "results":[{"registration_id":"(new registration id)","message_id":"0:123456"}]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there any way to get the new IID tokens from the old tokens, or to
>   create a mapping using the old tokens WITHOUT updating client app?"

You're right, you need Instance ID for mapping instances. There seems to be no mention of [registering to GCM topics](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server) using the deprecated version. Try the [Quickstart for Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) using Instance IDs.